Does “redeeming quality” simply mean “positive quality” today?
I want to understand if the meaning of the term “redeeming quality” has slightly changed recently. In tv shows, interviews etc. it is just used to describe a positive quality.
The use of the term redeeming quality, to me, only makes sense in the presence of another negative quality, and not when a positive quality is talked about by itself. There is nothing to redeem, in that case.
So has use of the term changed today such that it’s very loosely used?

Redeem/redeeming has a ton of meanings: the original theological sense, to pay a ransom, to pay off a mortgage/loan, to fulfil a promise, to regain or recover, to reclaim land, to make good use of, to pay for/buy, as well as to make amends for something bad. Your notion that it only has one narrow meaning isn't really correct.

@StuartF - I can see where John Red is coming from. In the context of a person's character, I would find mention of a 'redeeming' quality odd and annoying if there was no preceding mention of one or more 'bad' qualities. My aunt is a drunkard, a fascist, and a former member of the Stasi. However a redeeming quality is that she is kind to animals.

People use words without understanding them fully and when enough people do so, boom, you get a new dictionary entry.

@StuartF Agreed, on its own, "redeem" has many meanings, but in this case the OP is asking about the phrase "redeeming quality" which rules out the other meanings. A mortgage does not have a redeeming quality, it's just a debit that has to be repaid, sometimes by redeeming it.

Can you provide one or more quotes from TV to illustrate this possible new use of the phrase "redeaming quality"?

@David42 I did a Google Ngrams search, and looking at the book results for the most recent timespan, found this 'positive-only' usage: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Blended_Families_Recipes_for_Success/9SReEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22redeeming+qualities%22&pg=PA9&printsec=frontcover This is the first and so far only time I recall having seen the phrase used in this way.

@David42, so this was in a Game of Thrones interview where actors were asked if a character (Joffrey) had any redeeming qualities. They weren't even discussing the character before this question. Another example was in another interview where people talking about a presidential candidate's redeeming qualities.
I think bobsbeenjamin is right in a comment below. Even if the redeeming quality is not talked about in the context of an explicit negative quality, the negative qualities are sometimes implied or assumed. In these examples, simply by their profession - evil king, and a politician.

@John Red I would say that negative qualities are necessarily implied by the logic of the expression. The many meanings of "redeem" are derived from a common idea: to bring something of value in order to cancel some kind of debt or to cover some kind of loss. One redeems a pawned watch by repaying the loan with interest. One redeems a promise by doing what one said one would do. This also includes the theological senses: Jesus gave his life to pay off the debt of Adamic sin. So when we describe a good quality as "redeaming" we mean that it counterbalances one or more bad qualities or deeds.

As far as I know "redeeming quality" (often used in the phrase "the only redeeming quality") has always meant a possibly saving quality in the presence of otherwise negative qualities. For example "The only redeeming quality of the corrupt politician is that he supports a local children's charity."
The redeeming quality may not be sufficient to save the otherwise bad situation / person.

Yes, and it's nonsensical to present a 'redeeming' quality, whether it is the only one or not, without previously saying what it is supposed to redeem.

What @MichaelHarvey said. Also note that it's syntactically possible but semantically highly questionable to have multiple "redeeming qualities", since the context always requires that the subject would be beyond redemption were it not for the (normally singular) redeeming quality.

@FumbleFingers - I don't know about that...  And whatever his deficiencies, his redeeming qualities were of a rare kind. He was prodigally generous with his colleagues, tirelessly transcribing and performing their music, putting his own work as a composer second to the promotion of that of Berlioz and Wagner. [and he had] openness toward music of differing tendencies, championing, as he did, Verdi as well as Wagner, Tchaikovsky as well as the Russian “Five,” giving unstintingly of himself to all. Nor did he “react” against younger composers, as most others after a certain age have done.

@FumbleFingers - review of a life of Franz Liszt in the New York Review of Books. He was a serial shagger, I gather, before becoming a priest. No wonder Ken Russell made that film.

Hmm. I don't like that example, which I suspect embodies a clumsy attempt to emulate grandiose Victorian phrasing. See this usage chart showing how far plural redeeming qualities has fallen from grace over the past two centuries. To the point where his only redeeming quality has now overtaken plural his redeeming qualities.

...anyway, let's not get too bogged down in the minutiae of counterexamples. For learners today, it should be enough that they know a redeeming quality only just redeems the subject, who would otherwise be well past redemption.
'

This answer sums it up well. For non-native English speakers, I would add that the subject's poor qualities may be implied by their profession. For example, a politician, prostitute, or lawyer might be assumed to be bad, so it could be valid to say "the prosecutor's only redeeming quality is that she loves her husband."

@bobsbeenjamin Sorry I cannot agree with your statement. The occupation of the subject is not relevant. You're just basing your assertions on stereotypes mostly fictional. You can have completely honest politicians and prosecutors (why did you say prosecutor?) and totally corrupt or incompetent doctors and priests.

@PeterJennings that's true, though I think it's a fair point that the negative qualities mightn't be explicitly said by the speaker. And, for example, in the case of a profession, might be implied by their own personal biases/opinions

Saying someone has redeeming qualities implies that they have damning ones as well -- and that those are much more immediately obvious -- or they wouldn't need redemption.

@PeterJennings We're on the ELL site, not https://english.stackexchange.com/; as English-speaking natives, we should be instructing non-English speakers about idioms as much as proper English. I said "prosecutor" because a defense attorney (especially a public defender) has less assumed baggage than a prosecuting attorney (in common parlance). I agree that reality doesn't always match stereotypes, but stereotypes do affect patterns of speech.
